# Using PHP Files As CSS File With CSS Extension

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been doing some reading on using PHP files as CSS files.
I understand how to do that, but I want to take it a step further if possible.

Let's say I have a file called `main-styles.php` which contains my websites main style sheet.

If I want to link to this file I would simply use `<link rel="stylesheet href="http://example.com/css/main-styles.php">`.

Simple enough, but what I am wanting to do is instead of having a `.php` extension I would like to have a `.css` extension instead but the file still be `.php`.

Would this be possible through `mod_rewrite` or something?

I was thinking something like `RewriteRule ^(.+)\main-styles.php$ $1main-styles.css`.

Would that be sufficient?

If I'm not mistaken that rule would not work. I'm no expert in rewrite rules so bear with me.

EDIT

I've tried the following in my `.htaccess` file:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|png|jpe?g|gif)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule universal.css universal.php [L]`

Solved see my own answer.

Comment: Why? If it's CSS it's CSS and should have a .css extension.

Comment: Because it's really a PHP file, but in my source code I'd like for it to have a CSS extension. For security purposes I am trying to hide all of my PHP extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out finally. Turns out I had to list my directory.

Using the following in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|png|jpe?g|gif)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule css/universal.css css/universal.php [L]
```

I was able to keep my stylesheet a php file, but load it using a css extension.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/universal.css">`

Is handled as if it's

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/universal.php">`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the H or T flag of apach mode rewrite to force all files with php  extension to be parsed by The css handler :

try the following in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^main-style\.php$ - [H=text/css]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^main-style\.php$ - [T=text/css]
```

The rules above will change the mime type of main-style.php.

Comment: Isn't that equivilant to this? `header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");`